# tomcat not unpacking war when using custom context

Tags: tomcat, server, configuration, war

I q like to configure tomcat to serve   my application instead   of the default tomcat manager app.

So i use a     root.xml file containing a  context definition to my war file location.

```
<Context docBase="/usr/local/tomcat/custom-webapp/app.war" reloadable="true" />
```

The ROOT.xml file is in the directory /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/

All work fine but on tomcat start up , the war file isn't deployed. i expected tomcat unpack the file. 
is there something else to do ?

There is no error  in tomcat logs. Logs only say `INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`.

I'm sur that the config is good because when I erase the app.war file while tomcat is up, the war is unpacked.

Comment: What does the error log tell? And not sure if it's a difference, but try to name the file upper case `ROOT.xml`. Where did you copy that file to?

Comment: @Selaron i have updated the question. 
Yes the file is well named ROOT.xml. this is not the problem.

Comment: "like to configure tomcat to serve my application instead of the default tomcat manager app" - do you want to replace the `/manager` app? That's not going to happen by deploying an app to the root context path. Or what exactly is the issue? Is it that no files are being deployed, or is it that servlets from the app cannot be invoked from the browser?

Comment: i want to replace the /manager app by my own. 
I 'm using tomcat  docker container. So i have a shared volume that contains the app.war. when I start tomcat  the app is not deployed. but when i erase the war while tomcat is already up every thing work perfect (and i can access to  the app.war application